# Implementing Sort comparator for numerous field

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Java object with 15 fields(5 fields needs to be compared) and this object is contained in a arraylist. The arraylist needs to be sorted, so I need to implement the comparator interface...

How can I implement to comparator interface to compare one field after another...

Example:

```
Class Person(){
        private String fname;
        private String mname;
        private String lname;
        private String age;
        private String address;

        get/set methods;

        public static Comparator<Person> per = new Comparator<Person>{

        String x1 = ((Person) o1).getfame();
        String x2 = ((Person) o2).getfame();
        return x1 - x2;
        }

}
```

I'm able to implement the log for one field fname, but how can I implement all the remaining 4 fields(5 fields total).

Comment: Are you trying to sort them in a certain priority order?

Comment: @spudone:Yes, it should be fname, lname, mname, age and address

Comment: I did the googling for you: [1](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/), [2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm), [3](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/), [4](http://www.journaldev.com/780/java-comparable-and-comparator-example-to-sort-objects)

Comment: Comparator isn't needed; just needs to implement Comparable and override compareTo

Comment: @Tom: Thanks...but I need a method that compares multiple fields..those docs talks about one field...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this then:

```
public int compareTo(Person other) {
    int comp = fname.compareTo(other.fname); //Try fname first.
    if(comp != 0) return comp; //But if the fnames are equal, try the next field.
    comp = lname.compareTo(other.lname); //And so on...
    if(comp != 0) return comp;
    comp = mname.compareTo(other.mname);
    if(comp != 0) return comp;
    comp = age.compareTo(other.age);
    if(comp != 0) return comp;
    return address.compareTo(other.address); //At the last field, you can return 0 even if they are equal.
}
```

Make sure the `Person` class implements `Comparable<Person>`, and you should be able to sort them in your list.

Edit: Interested by your question, I've been reading up on sorting strings, and it turns out that the above code works, but sorts case sensitively. This may be sufficient for your purposes, but means that `"Z"` will get sorted before `"a"` since `"Z"` is a capital letter and those get a lower Unicode index.

Apparently, there is a pre-built comparator in `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` that compares strings such that `"Z"` will properly get placed behind `"a"`. If you want to use that, use `int comp = String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(fname,other.fname);` (and repeat for every field). There is also a class `java.text.Collator` that will sort other localities than English properly. I learned something new today!

Comment: Side note: on both of these answers, the Strings should be null-checked to avoid a potential exception on sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

    private String fname;
    private String mname;
    private String lname;
    private String age;
    private String address;
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }
    public String getMname() {
        return mname;
    }
    public void setMname(String mname) {
        this.mname = mname;
    }
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o2) {

        return  
        (fname+lname+mname+age+address).compareTo(o2.fname+o2.lname+o2.mname+o2.age+o2.address);
    }
```

}

Comment: Quite clever to append the strings! It really cleans up the code. That method name should be `compareTo` rather than `compare` and only take the `o2` parameter, then it ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*You can try this*/
    package test1;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;

    public class PersonComparisonTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Person p1 = new Person("A","B","C","L","28");
            Person p2 = new Person("X","Y","Z","N","29");
            Person p3 = new Person("L","M","N","M","30");
            ArrayList persons = new ArrayList();
            persons.add(p1);
            persons.add(p2);
            persons.add(p3);
            printDATA(persons.toArray());
            Collections.sort(persons, new PersonComparator());
            printDATA(persons.toArray());
        }
        public static void printDATA(Object[] als) {  
            for(int i=0; i < als.length; i++) {  
                System.out.println(als[i]);  
            }  
        }
    }
    class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person>{

        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2){
            int i = p1.getFname().compareTo(p2.getFname());
            if (i != 0) return i;

            i = p2.getMname().compareTo(p2.getMname());
            if (i != 0) return i;

            i = p2.getLname().compareTo(p2.getLname());
            if (i != 0) return i;

            i = p2.getAddress().compareTo(p2.getAddress());
            if (i != 0) return i;

            return Integer.valueOf(p1.getAge()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(p2.getAge()));
        }

    }

    class Person{
        private String fname;
        private String mname;
        private String lname;
        private String age;
        private String address;
        public Person(String fname, String mname, String lname, String address,String age) {
            super();
            this.fname = fname;
            this.mname = mname;
            this.lname = lname;
            this.address = address;
            this.age = age;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person [fname=" + fname + ", mname=" + mname + ", lname="
                    + lname + ", age=" + age + ", address=" + address + "]";
        }
        public String getFname() {
            return fname;
        }
        public void setFname(String fname) {
            this.fname = fname;
        }
        public String getMname() {
            return mname;
        }
        public void setMname(String mname) {
            this.mname = mname;
        }
        public String getLname() {
            return lname;
        }
        public void setLname(String lname) {
            this.lname = lname;
        }
        public String getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(String age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }
        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
    }
```